# android memory leak android.view.ViewRoot$ Native Stack

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

In my android app I have a memory leak problem. I think Activity are not `GC`-ed. i use MAT to analyze my app but I do not know about MAT.
I found that there is 7 '`DecorView`' object that take most of memory and all of them root to `GC` is `android.view.ViewRoot$ Native Stack.`
What is '`android.view.ViewRoot$ Native Stack'`? And how to solve this problem?

```
Class Name                                       | Ref. Objects | Shallow Heap | Ref. Shallow Heap | Retained Heap
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
android.view.ViewRoot$1 @ 0x2b5def20 Native Stack|            1 |           16 |                80 |            16
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```